# Can you use information acquired during the research (and listed in the appendix) in the introduction?

Tags: introduction, supporting-information

In some fields of research, e.g. ecology, it is common to describe the study area in which some field experiment was conducted. However, sometimes you find out some facts that might be of interest only during the field work itself.

I am currently not sure about whether it is ok to put such information in the appendix of a paper and reference the appendix in the introduction or methods section. The information was acquired entirely during the field work and is not available anywhere else (hence, some entirely new knowledge); however, it is not some result or output of the study but simple, basic facts. E.g., the number of tree species occurring in the area, or information about the climate that were calculated based on data from some weather station, in a study that tests some hypothesis not directly related to these environmental factors.

Maybe I am giving too much thought to this, but I have little experience so far and do not want to make some mistake.

Answer (score 2):

At this point in your career, you should have read already many papers in your field. You should find examples on what you plan to do there.

Prima facie, you provide information that might be useful to the readers of your paper, who might be looking for a good area to study themselves. Putting this type of information in an appendix seems entirely appropriate. Once it is anywhere in the paper, your introduction can and usually should allude to it. If it is very short, you might want to describe your study area in the introduction itself.